# Using Bubble-Sort for Two-Dimensional Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I am looking to modify a bubble sort that I used for a one-dimensional array in order for it to sort a two-dimensional array. I honestly am just having a pretty hard time figuring out the necessary changes. My code is below.

Any help/feedback is appreciated, thanks!

```
int n;
int temp;

System.out.print("Please enter how large you want the array to be: ");
n = in.nextInt();
int sorting[] = new int[n];
System.out.println("Please enter the elements you want in the array: ");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    sorting[i] = in.nextInt();
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
    {
        if (sorting[i] > sorting[j]) 
        {
            temp = sorting[i];
            sorting[i] = sorting[j];
            sorting[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
System.out.print("Here is your array in ascending order: ");
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
{
    System.out.print(sorting[i] + ",");
}
System.out.print(sorting[n - 1]);
```

Comment: Where is your second dimension?

Comment: How do you define a two-dimensional array as "sorted"? Are the rows in your two-dimensional array always going to be the same length?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes the rows will be the same length, I am thinking of doing a simple 4x4 two-dimensional array or something similar.

Comment: @ReneM. My second dimension is not included here because my question is "how to modify a one-dimensional bubble sort to be used in a two-dimensional array". Going along with that, I wanted to include my bubble sort that is just suited for a one-dimensional array.

Comment: OK, so how do you define "sorted"? If you have, say, first row `5 2 10`, second row `11 3 5` and third row `17 7 3`. What would the sorted array look like?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I would like the array to be sorted in ascending order. Based on your input, I would like the output to look something like:  2,5,10 (next line) 3,5,11 (next row) 3,7,17.

Comment: So that just means that every row is sorted, not that the array is sorted. Then all you need to do is iterate your array, and apply your bubble sort to each row separately.

Comment: We should stop doing his homework ;)

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for the insight, that clears up the thinking for me. I believe my problem was that I was tackling a two-dimensional array all at once and it just seemed very complex. I appreciate the help.